# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (AB e_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (Be_n, e_m) (Ae_m, e_n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $A$ and $B$ bounded linear operators on $H$, and $\{e_n\}$ an orthonormal basis for $H$. I am following a proof that claims it is obvious that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (AB e_n, e_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (Be_n, e_m) (Ae_m, e_n).$$
However I do not see why this is necessarily true. How can one prove this?

Comment: The formula $\langle ABe_n,e_n\rangle =\langle Be_n,A^*e_n\rangle$ and the Parseval identity.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you. How would you use the Parseval identity here? Would you mind writing it as an answer?

Comment: Note that while the identity holds without the outer summation over $n$, the series on both sides can diverge (take for example $Ae_n=(-1)^n e_n$, $B_n=1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically just uses that any vector $v$ in a seperable Hilbert space $H$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2,...,\}$ can be expressed as $v = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (v,e_n) e_n$.

So one has $B e_n = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty (B e_n,e_m)e_m$ and since $A$ is a linear operator, i.e. $A(\lambda v) = \lambda A(v)$ for any $v\in H$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, this means that \begin{align*}
(AB)e_n &= A(Be_n)\\
 &= A\left(\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty (B e_n,e_m)e_m\right)\\
& = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty (B e_n,e_m) A e_m
\end{align*}
So if we now take the scalar product $(ABe_n,e_n)$ and sum over all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we get the desired equality:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (ABe_n,e_n) &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(A \left( \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty (B e_n,e_m)e_m\right),e_n\right)\\
&= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty (B e_n,e_m) (Ae_m,e_n)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

For two elements $x, y$ in $H$ by the Parseval identity we have
$$ \langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \langle x, e_m \rangle \overline{\langle y, e_m \rangle} \\ = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \langle x, e_m \rangle \langle e_m, y \rangle. $$
Hence
$$ \langle A B e_n, e_n \rangle = \langle B e_n, A^\ast e_n \rangle \\ = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \langle B e_n, e_m \rangle \langle e_m, A^\ast e_n \rangle \\ = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \langle B e_n, e_m \rangle \langle A e_m, e_n \rangle. $$

Comment: This is very neat, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

$$B e_n = \sum_{m} \langle B e_n, e_m \rangle e_m \text{, so } \langle A B e_n, e_n \rangle = \sum_m \langle B e_n, e_m \rangle \langle A e_m, e_n \rangle$$
and summing over $n$ yields the result.